# How to have NetworkId (Community Id) logic working in both production and unit tests?

Tags: apex, unit-test, community, contentversion, contentdocument

Some existing product code that creates `ContentVersion` instances is now being called from a community and the code fails with:

> INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, You do not have the
> level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested.
> Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access
> is necessary.: [NetworkId]

The [ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) documentation says:

> Customer and Partner Portal users must also supply the NetworkId of
> the community in the request.

So code like this
is needed where the `NetworkId` is set:

```
insert new ContentVersion(
    Title = ...,
    VersionData = ...,
    PathOnClient = ...,
    FirstPublishLocationId = ...,
    NetworkId = Network.getNetworkId()
);
```

and this does fix the problem.

But looking at other posts here e.g. [Testing with Community User, getNetworkId = null](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/148479/testing-with-community-user-getnetworkid-null) it seems like in unit tests `Network.getNetworkId()` always returns null, including when `System.runAs` is used with a community user. So I assume that to have code that works for both unit tests and production I would need a method that looks something like this:

```
public static String getNetworkId() {
    // In tests Network.getNetworkId() returns null so use this alternative
    if (Test.isRunningTest()) {
        // If multiple memberships take newest
        for (NetworkMember m : [
                select NetworkId
                from NetworkMember
                where MemberId = :UserInfo.getUserId()
                order by Id desc
                limit 1
                ]) {
            return m.NetworkId;
        }
        return null;
    } else {
        return Network.getNetworkId();
    }
}
```

If you have solved this problem do share your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
User portalUser = getPortalUser();

// Ran as system
Id networkId = [
      SELECT NetworkId, MemberId
      FROM NetworkMember
      WHERE MemberId = :customerPortalUser.Id
].NetworkId;

System.runAs(portalUser) {
   insert new ContentVersion(
         Title = 'Title',
         PathOnClient = 'Path on client',
         VersionData = Blob.valueOf('Version Data'),
         NetworkId = networkId
   );
}
```